# Matplotlib plotting alignment error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 3d

I'm trying to build a 3d graph using matplotlib and python2.7 in Linux. but the alignment of the image is not set right.

[image]

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = list(xrange(0,51))
y = list(xrange(0,9))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zs = np.array([fun(x,y) for x,y in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,9), ['0.8', '1.0', '1.2', '1.4', '1.6','1.8','2.0','2.2','2.4'])
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,51, 10.0))
plt.gray()
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency (GHz)')
ax.set_xlabel('Clamping States')
ax.set_zlabel('Power(W)')
plt.savefig('final' + '.jpg', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.2,dpi=100)
plt.clf()


def fun(x, y):
    return power_matrix[x][y]

power_matrix = [[] for a in range(0, len(clamp_ranges))]
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? Why is the alignment not correct?

Comment: What's wrong with the alignment, exactly? Rather, what is it that you are calling "un-aligned" here?

Comment: The 0 on the clamping states axis has to start at the very beginning and not at 10.

Comment: I don't know matplotlib specifically, but this looks like an intentional feature of many plotting libraries, where they pad the axes a bit so the data doesn't collide with the edge of the plot.  Is this *bad* for some reason?  Look in the documentation for "axis expansion" or "axis padding".